# Is there any way to see iPhone logs on Mac's Console over wifi?

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, xcode

As the title says, is there any way to read the console logs without connecting the iphone to the mac via USB? I've tried putting the iPhone on the same Wi-Fi and it still does not work.

I need to debug a behaviour that happens when the iPhone is not charging.

Also, from Xcode *devices & simulators* window the option "Open Console" is greyed out. View Device Logs does not show the same amount of detail.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904753/view-iphone-console-logs-without-a-mac) and see if the answers help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the device list in the left sidebar, it's possible to provide an IP address by right clicking the device. As long as both are in the same network Xcode will be able to connect to the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

An oldish thread but I came across just the opposite problem, or perhaps the answer.
I was chasing a random power-off bug on my Mac Mini and decided to look in the logs for when the Mac rebooted. I found this; my iPhone logs streaming up the screen. I had no idea this was a thing. I switched off the phone's WiFi and the logging stopped on the mini. [image: the log.]